# Как задать название видео которое будет скачано?

Tags: python-3.x

В данном коде название видео задается согласно названию ролика на ютубе
А как сделать чтоб название ролика было (video.mp4)

> ```
> link=input("link")        
> print("link is-"+link)
> yt = YouTube(link)
> print(yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4'))
> stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
> stream.download()
> print("done!")
> ```

Comment: Что такое `YouTube` в этом коде?

Comment: Что именно здесь название видео?

Answer (score 1):

```
stream.download(filename='filename.mp4')
```